# Acessar tempData c# e mostrar no alert

Tags: mvc, razor

Eu estou tentando exibir uma mensagem de acordo com o retorno do meu método, que é um `Task<ActionResult>` , porém quando eu chamo a `TempData`, ela está vindo vazia, onde estou errando?

```
@section scripts {
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $("#button-submit").click(function ()
    {
      alert('@(TempData["CurrentTab"])');
    })
  </script>
}
```

estes são os retornos do meu form

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ApiLServico.ContatoObject _user, string cpf,
     string ddd, string telefone, int Niveis)
         TempData["Message"] = res;

             {...condições...}

          return View();
        }
        TempData["Message"] = "Ocorreu um erro";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
      }
      catch (Exception ex) { TempData["Message"] = ex.ToString(); 
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); } 
    }
    TempData["Message"] = "Por favor preencha todos os campos" ;
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Como posso fazer para isso funcionar da forma correta passando as mensagens que quero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui uma solução, na verdade só precisei atribuir a variável

```
 @section scripts {
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $("#button-submit").click(function () {

       var message = '@TempData["Message"]';
         alert(message);
     })
   </script>
 }
```